# Changing landing page of website hosted on sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I have a collection of sites hosted on sharepoint and I'm trying to change the welcome page from pages/default.aspx to one of the site's pages/default.aspx. When I try to do that normally, I get an error saying:-
The specified welcome page is not valid or does not exist within the current site.

I read up on it and found that this can be resolved by copying the default.aspx page from that site's pages to main pages folder. However, I get an error:-
You may re-try the operation, and you may need to clean up the half-created data first before re-trying.

I cannot find the place where publishing can be enabled which has been suggested as a resolution to this error.

Can someone help me and tell me how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: are you using team site in sp2010? Did you tried this with Sharepoint Designer?

Comment: Can't access the site using sharepoint designer 2007. I am using sp2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a sub site page cannot be converted into a landing page directly. The workaround that I used was to create a redirect page in the main site and make it the landing page. The users can then be redirected to the subsite page once they land on the redirection page.